# Errno 13 permission denied: 'C\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\JAP\Lib\site-packages\sip.pyd\'

Tags: python, anaconda

Este error me aparece al intentar instalar pytorch, me aparece intentando instalarlo con los siguientes commandos:

"conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch"

"conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch"

como puedo solucionar este error?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: la solucion es simple `inicio->buscar->cmd->click derecho->ejecutar como administrador`

Comment: como hago para iniciar la consola desde el entorno de anaconda como administrador?